# What is the difference between $:=$ and $:\iff$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the difference between
$:=$ and $:\iff$? Which one is used when (and how ist the latter called)?

I've seen the following: $$ X \subset Y :\iff \forall x \in X: x \in Y$$

Why cannot it be written with like this/What difference does this formulation make?: $$ X \subset Y := \forall x \in X: x \in Y$$

Thank you!

**EDIT** I'm asking specifically about the $:\iff$ Operator and not about the $\iff$ without the colon.

Comment: := means by definition, you wanna define what X $\subset$ Y means, when you want to use it in proofs, you use the $ \leftrightarrow $ one

Comment: The first expression makes no sense to me. The first colon shouldn't be there.

Comment: $:=$ is typically used for definitions, which carry an *if and only if* meaning

Comment: @ChubbyChef My Prof. wrote it like this in his script (thats why I was wondering). I know the $\iff$ and the $:=$ operator, but cannot explain to myself what the $:\iff$ might mean.

Comment: The more common meaning of ":=" is an assignment. "$a:=3$" defines $a$ to be $3$. For "if and only if" common notations are "iff" or "$\iff$"

Comment: Where I learned math a long time ago, they used $\overset{\text{def}}{\iff}$ to mean "LHS is defined to be equivalent to RHS". Not sure how widespread that notation is.

Comment: @StinkingBishop that might lead to an answer of my question. Thank you.

Comment: See the post [What's the difference among the logical relations $:=, =$, and $\iff$ ?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/19773/whats-the-difference-among-the-logical-relations-and-%e2%89%a1)

Comment: (Cont'd) They also used $\overset{\text{def}}=$ to mean what we normally write as $:=$ BTW...

Comment: It seems that he is using $: \Leftrightarrow$ in the [defintion : $X \subseteq Y \text {  iff  } \forall x (x \in A \to x \in Y)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#Definitions). Thus, it is a "variant" of the more common symbol $\Leftrightarrow$ used for "$\text {  iff  }$".

Comment: @StinkingBishop That answered my question. You can make this an answer so I can mark it as solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First there is a difference between equality and equivalence. Equality holds between objects while equivalence holds between formulas, sentences, propositions. Objects ( numbers, functions, curves, etc.) are not true or false, only propostions  are, and they are logically equivalent just in case they have the same truth value in all possible situation.

Example . The proposition  (A&~B) is not the same proposition as ~ ( A$\rightarrow B$); however they are equivalent.

So, properly speaking, one should not use an equal symbol between two expressions ( though one can see this in old logic books).

- Second, some propositions are logically equivalent just because we decide them to be so, that is, we use one proposition as a definition of the other. In that case they are equivalent by definition , and we can write " $  X:\iff Y$ or " $X\equiv_{Df} Y$. "
- To put it briefly, *equivalence-by-definition* is a special case of logical equivalence ( and is not the same relation as equality).

Comment: Thank you so much! @FloridusFloridi

Answer (score 0):

The mysterious "$:\iff$" symbol is, disappointingly, the result of a typo in the first expression. It *should* say $$ X\subset Y \iff \forall x \in X : x \in Y.$$ We *could*, if we wanted to, replace $\iff$ with $:=$ in the above expression, but this wouldn't be standard notation, as $:=$ is mostly reserved for direct definitions, e.g. $x:=10$, and not for more complex mathematical statements.

Comment: It is not a typo but systematically used, which is why I got confused and asked the question.

Comment: @NilsK then this notation is peculiar to your professor, and you should ask him for clarification.